# getchar vs scanf: why won't getchar work?

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

I wrote a simple program to input a number and return any value which when divided by it will return a remainder of 3.

I'm currently reading K&R and it doesn't teach scanf until something like Chapter 7 so I tried to use getchar. It doesn't work, but scanf does. What am I doing wrong?

```
int main()
{
    int c, i;

    printf("Input an integer: ");
    //c = getchar();
    scanf("%d", &c);

    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        if ((i % c) == 3) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Optional side question: It seems like people here have been advising not to start with K&R. What might be a better alternative for a beginner?

Comment: You are not inputting an integer. You are inputting a single character.

Comment: That is because they do different jobs. When you enter 3 with `scanf` you get the value `3` and with `getchar` you receive the character `'3'`, which in ASCII encoding is the value `51`.

Comment: `getchar` reads a single octet, but it returns an int so that it can return a value to indicate when no data was read.  That is, it can only return a value between 0 and 255.  If your input is the string '4357', it just reads the `4` and returns the value of `4` in the local character set. (eg, 52 is a commonly used value )

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for this. That explains the results I'm getting. So is there any way to use getchar here and convert it to the value '3'?

Comment: Furthermore they cover different ranges: even with some weird conversion in order to get an integer number, with getchar() you can obtain at most a value of 255. With scanf you get signed integers.

Comment: Only if you build the number yourself, from its digits. Otherwise you are limited to the values `0` to `9` which you can convert it with `c - '0'` provided you know that it *is* a digit!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
scanf("%d", &c);
```

Is requesting `scanf()` to read *an integer value* from standard input. The `scanf()` function will read from standard input as much characters as needed, and then *parse them* into an integer, storing the value in the variable `c` (i.e. at the address pointed by `&c`). The return value of `scanf()` also communicates the number of correctly parsed items, so in this case you should check if the returned value is `1`.

This:

```
c = getchar();
```

Is requesting `getchar()` to read *a single character* from standard input. The `getchar()` function will try to read a character, and will return it (casted to an `int`) in case of success. In case of error or end of file, the special integer value `EOF` will be returned. The fact that `getchar()` returns an `int` doesn't mean that the function will parse the input like `scanf("%d", ...)` does. Indeed, the return value has type `int` only because it's needed to distinguish a valid character from `EOF`.

To know more, refer to the manual pages for `scanf` and `getchar` using the `man` command, e.g. `man scanf`. Consulting manual pages is important to understand the semantics of a function. **Always read the manual**. Alternatively, you can look it up online: [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html), [`getchar()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getchar.3p.html).

---

If you want to scan *a single character* using `getchar()` and convert it into an integer, then you can do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // getchar(), puts()
#include <ctypes.h> // isdigit()

int main(void) }
    int c;

    c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF) {
        puts("Error!");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!isdigit(c)) {
        puts("Character is not a digit!");
        return 1;
    }

    int value = c - '0';
    // value now holds the integer corresponding to the digit that was read from input

    /* ... */

    return 0;
}
```

Note: `c - '0'` works because characters representing digits have sequentially increasing values in the ASCII table (from 0x30 to 0x39). See also [`man ascii`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html).

Answer (score 0):

`getchar` reads one symbol from the inputs stream and returns it as its integer value of its internal representation or `EOF`.

So to read a number that has at least two digits you have to call `getchar` several times and then convert the symbols' representations to the corresponding integer number.

Opposite to `getchar` `scanf` tries to read a whole number as an integer if you specified the conversion format `%d` or similar specially designed to read numbers

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how your program can be implemented using `getchar`. In the program there is no check whether the user entered a too big number. You can add such a check yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const unsigned int REMAINDER = 3;

    printf( "Input a non-negative integer: " );

    unsigned int n = 0;

    for ( int c; ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && isdigit( ( unsigned char )c ); )
    {
        const unsigned int Base = 10;

        n = Base * n + ( c - '0' );
    }


    if ( n > REMAINDER )
    {
        const unsigned int N = 100;
        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        {
            if ( ( i + 1 ) % n == REMAINDER ) printf( "%u ", i + 1 );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look for example like

```
Input a non-negative integer: 10
3 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83 93
```

As for books then it is always difficult to read a book on a language or technology  which you are not familiar yet.

Comment: AFAIK the cast to `unsigned char` is only required for values of type `char`, it's ok to pass `c` as is to `isdigit()`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli As a result the passed integer can be considered in the function as a negative character value.:)